# Cannot Implement Searching By Name

Tags: c++

So I have created a program to store the info of students in a file and the program creates the file and stores the info but does not search upon selecting the option and says the name not found. I have tried to implement a search by name here. I am a beginner so any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Students
{
    private:
        string name[5];
        int age;
        string regNo;
    public:

        void writing();
        int search();
            
};
void Students::writing(){
    int a;
    string r;
    string n[5];
    name[5] = n[5];
    int age = a;
    string regNo = r;
    
    fstream file;
    file.open("studentsinfo.txt",ios::app);
    
    if(!file){
        cout<<"Error in creating file!"<<endl;
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"Enter Name: ";
        cin>>n[i];
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter Age: ";
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"\nEnter Registration No: ";
        cin>>r;
    }
    
    for(int j=0; j<=5; j++)
    {
        file<<"Name: "<<n[j]<<endl;
        file<<"Age: "<<a<<endl;
        file<<"Registration Number: "<<r<<endl;
        
        file.close();
}
    
    
    
}
int Students::search(){
    string n;
    cout<<"Enter the name you want to search: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i=i+1)
    {
        if(n==name[i])
        {
            cout<<"Name found: "<<i+1;
            
            break;
        }
        if(!(n==name[i])){
            cout<<"Name not found! "<<endl;
            
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    
    cout<<"Enter 1 for Writing to file. ";
    cout<<"\nEnter 2 for Searching in File. ";
    int choice;
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            if(choice == 1){
                Students s1;
                s1.writing();
            }
        case 2:
            if(choice == 2){
                Students s2;
                s2. search();
            }   
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `search` logic is incorrect.  You always print something and then `break` after checking the first name, regardless of whether or not it matched.  You should only print `"Name not found"` after checking *all* students.

Comment: `name[5] = n[5];` and `n[j]` in `for(int j=0; j<=5; j++)` are dangerous out-of-range access.

Comment: The name not found should happen after the loop. Instead of breaking in the loop return i. I guess return -1 if not found.

Comment: @0x5453 I just don't understand the logic and implementation here.

Comment: Didn't you write this code?

Comment: I don't know what you think `name[5] = n[5]` is supposed to do, but it won't do it. It's going out of bounds of both arrays and lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: `s2. search()` will currently search over an empty array.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I wrote this on my own.

Comment: In e.g. `case 1` it's already guaranteed that `choice` is equal to `1`, you don't need to check for it again.

Comment: Don't know what I am doing here. Have been on it for hours. Can someone fix this?

Comment: probably just nitpicking but seeing a `class Students` instead of `class Student` and then an `std::vector<Student> Student_vector` rubs me the wrong way and is really throwing me off. At first i thought you had a 5 digit name for the students

Comment: Actually looking more at the code i just noticed that you are using the same `age` and `regNo` for all the different `name[5]`, I really think you should reconsider your whole approach rather than try and ifix the search right now since you'll most likely have to change it anyway (unless all the students do have the same `age` and `regNo`, in that case that's a really strange school)

Comment: Also you are not actually putting anything in `name[5]`, `age` and `regNo` so your search won't find anything since all the names are `""` (empty string)

Comment: In writing don't create new variables a, n, regNo  and r. Just use the class members. `for(int j=0; j<=5; j++)` should be `for(int j=0; j<5; j++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a simple mistake in the for loop. You are breaking from loop if not found in the first iteration. If not found you have to loop until last element of the array.

```
int Students::search(){
    string n;
    cout<<"Enter the name you want to search: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i=i+1)
    {
        if(n==name[i])
        {
            cout<<"Name found: "<<i+1;
            
            return i;
        }
        if(n!=name[i] && i == 4){
            cout<<"Name not found! "<<endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Else you can try this also. That after whole array is searched and name is still not found.

```
int Students::search(){
    string n;
    cout<<"Enter the name you want to search: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i=i+1)
    {
        if(n==name[i])
        {
            cout<<"Name found: "<<i+1;
            return i; //Return directly from function if found else continue
        }
    }
    cout<<"Name not found! "<<endl;
    return -1;
}
```